# Open Graph Search - How to post custom actions so Facebook users will find them via new Graph Search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

I am developing an Open Graph Facebook application that is still in sandbox mode. My test users that are my friends have posted a fair amount of actions via the application and I do see them on the graph when querying it using `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=<namespace>:<action>`. My purpose is to make these custom actions and the objects they related to visible via the new Facebook Graph Search.

I do not find a way via the new Graph Search to view these same actions or objects. Do you have an idea what should be the search text or what I should do within my application to make them visible?

Answer (score 2):

I was investigating the same recently. My final result was that the available actions / verbs available via the regular graphsearch interface are restricted to what facebook provides. I found no way to get my custom actions / verbs to show up.

Comment: Thanks ThomasS for the update. Did you get any confirmation from Facebook it is indeed their intent to restrict their graph search to only their built-in graph types?

Comment: No sorry no official statement. I came to the conclusion via method of elimination. There is just no information (i could find) how to publish custom actions at this time.

Answer (score -2):

Try `FQL`:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me() ) AND is_app_user&access_token=|ACCES_TOKEN|
```

It will list all your friend who use your app.

Comment: Thanks Newbie and indeed it works. But I am looking for a way to expose my app custom objects to the end user via the the Facebook application User Interface, via the new search bar. I wonder how this new Graph Search bar will surface custom objects. Is it via a specific  syntax inside the search or via specific parameters in the object post in graph.